# Why am I getting an 'Element type is invalid' error in my React Native app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

```
`import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';
import { HomeScreen } from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-view';


// Redux installed


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <HomeScreen />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});`
```

ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here are the other files:
HomeScreen.js:

```
`import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";
import NavOptions from '../components/NavOptions';

/// Tailwind CSS 
const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>
      <View style = {tw`p-5`}>
        <Image
        style ={{ 
            width:100, 
            height:100, 
            resizeMode: 'contain',
        }}
            source = {{
                uri:"https://links.papareact.com/gzs",
            }}
        />
        <NavOptions />

      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        color:"blue",
    },
});`
```

store.js

```
`import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { navReducer } from "./slices/navSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        nav: navReducer,
    },
});`
```

I've tried looking at react elements to fix it but none of them have helped. I feel like it might be something to do with NPM?

Comment: These codes looks okay. What about the <NavOptions /> component? can you share its code?

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting `HomeScreen` like a default module, you need to import without the curly-brackets.

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

Comment: Changed it, same error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check all your imports, i found this error in another import:`import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-view';`  (This import doesn't need curly-brackets, info from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-view)), check the corresponding docs for all your modules if error still exists.